# .vimrc overrides existing settings

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

The admin on our server gave everyone  a `.vim/vimrc` file, which has all the settings I want, except for one I want to change. (I am not allowed to change the `.vim/vimrc` file) I read up on it, and I created a `.vimrc` file, which contains the line: `set nowrap`. Once this is created, all the admin settings are gone, leaving me with this ugly version I don't want. When I change the name or delete it, the admin settings are back, but I don't have the `non-wrapping` lines. How can I get the best of both wrold and keep the non wraping lines + the admin settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `.vimrc`, put

```
source ~/.vim/vimrc " This will execute everything in that file (one which you were given)
set nowrap
```

`source` will execute everything `~/.vim/vimrc` and even if there are any wraping setting in that file, the setting you provide in `~/.vimrc` will override it.